# Bug in Career 2.0 Search after change in UI recently

Tags: bug, search, tag-search, jobs

When I come from main career 2.0 site. I clicked on PHP from there. Then it came to search listing page and it worked fine. Then I choose location and then on pressing enter or clicking search button, it duplicated PHP, so this time search field had "PHP PHP" mean two times written in it. I again clicked Search and a "PHP" in search field increased and then this was the URL:
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/php?searchTerm=php+php+php&location=UAE&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles

And in search box there were "PHP PHP PHP PHP" while 3 times PHP in search term in URL as given above. So this need to be fixed because if it occur, it don't return any search result.